# Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, iis-7, exception, out-of-memory

I am facing a System.OutOfMemory in web application, it happen when i try to execute a havy report which almost 50,000 records.

I have 16 GM Ram on my server also when i execute this report then i have checked the Memory in Tasks Manager and found that there are only 3.1 GB in used also CPU utilization in 20-24%.

I am unable find out the cause of memory exception.

Comment: 32-bit or 64-bit application?

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me a few times and the cause was always the same.

If you manually register events somewhere in your code and don't manually remove them later you will amass static references that never get Garbage Collected.

So if you += an event handler somewhere on one of your pages (or even the master page) -= it if you don't need it anymore.